# need to check background process is stopped or not and later add mapping for processor id

Tags: shell, process, mapping

In our script we run the function in the background and stored their processor id in one file, we stored 6 background processors id in one file likewise we have 6 files each having 6 processor IDs.
Now we need to check all those processors should complete their job so that we can run another function
Check continuously in an infinite loop whether the processor is completed or not.
when the processor is stopped do processor mapping

```
while true; do
   for file in $(ls status); do
    while read line; do
       pgrep -x $line
    if [[ "$?" = "1" ]]; then
        log "$line is completed"
    fi
    break
    done < status/$file
    done
done
```

status folder contains files, each file contains 6 process id

Comment: Did the answer given solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env sh

# Fail on error
set -o errexit
# Enable wildcard character expansion
set +o noglob

# ================
# CONFIGURATION
# ================
# PID directory
PID_DIR="status"
# Sleep time in seconds
SLEEP_TIME=1

# ================
# LOGGER
# ================
# Fatal log message
fatal() {
  printf '[FATAL] %s\n' "$@" >&2
  exit 1
}

# Warning log message
warn() {
  printf '[WARN ] %s\n' "$@" >&2
}

# Info log message
info() {
  printf '[INFO ] %s\n' "$@"
}

# ================
# MAIN
# ================
{
  # Check command 'ps' exists
  command -v ps > /dev/null 2>&1 || fatal "Command 'ps' not found"
  # Check command 'sleep' exists
  command -v sleep > /dev/null 2>&1 || fatal "Command 'sleep' not found"

  # Iterate files
  for _file in "$PID_DIR"/*; do
    # Skip if not file
    [ -f "$_file" ] || continue

    info "Analyzing file '$_file'"

    # Iterate PID
    while IFS='' read -r _pid; do
      info "Analyzing PID '$_pid'"

      # Wait PID
      while true; do
        info "Checking PID '$_pid'"

        # Check PID
        if ps -p "$_pid" > /dev/null 2>&1; then
          # PID exists
          warn "PID '$_pid' not terminated. Sleeping '$SLEEP_TIME' seconds..."
          sleep "$SLEEP_TIME"
        else
          # PID not exists
          info "PID '$_pid' terminated"
          break
        fi
      done
    done < "$_file"
  done

  # PIDs terminated
  info "All PIDs terminated"

  # ...
}
```

#### Note

Because `wait` only works if the script is the PID's parent, you must continually poll for its existance with `ps`.